# Elastic Search: How to get an exact match for each field in a cross-fields multi-match search?

Tags: field, match, phrase, elasticsearch

I'm trying to do an exact location search, meaning that each term in the location should exactly match at least one location field. For example, if I search for "Sudbury, Middlesex, Massachusetts" then I want to only get results that have an exact match for each of those three terms. A result with location.city.name = Sudbury, location.county.name = Middlesex, and location.region.name = Massachusetts would match.

```
{
"multi_match": {
    "fields": [
        "location.city.name",
        "location.region.name",
        "location.county.name",
        "location.country.name"
    ],
    "query": "Sudbury, Middlesex, Massachusetts",
    "type": "cross_fields",
    "operator": "and"
}
```

This is very close, however I also get results for "East Sudbury." I don't want East Sudbury, I only want results that match the field exactly. How can I do this? I know that "type":"phrase" is wrong because then it would be searching for the entire phrase "Sudbury, Middlesex, Massachusetts" in each field and would get no results.

Comment: Did u perhaps find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the field location.city.name is being analysed and splitting 'East Sudbury' into 'East' and 'Sudbury' and getting returned for a search for 'Sudbury'

Try setting the field to not_analyzed if you are always searching for specific terms?